# Download Full Directory to Client Through URL Express JS

Tags: node.js, express, download

I am trying to send a directory full of files to the client. So far, I have been trying to use the Express JS helper function res.download(). However that is only working for single files. How can I send a full directory from my Node server to the client?

```
// works when path includes file inside /files
router.get('/points-stats-csv', function(req, res, next) {
    var dir = '../public/files/'
    res.download(dir, 'points-stats.csv')
})
```

Comment: zip the directory and send the archive to the client.

Answer (score 2):

You can't send a directory.

Directory is a file system structure, and the contents are index and locations on the disk of the files in *that* folder.

So, like written in the comments, you need to pack (zip) all the files pointed by that folders into a single file, and then send that single file.